# How can I pass a python object to a function which requires a pointer type

Tags: python, c++, swig

I used swig to wrap some C++ Api to Python.

The c++ api looks like this.

```
class CThostFtdcMdSpi
{
public:
virtual void OnFrontConnected(){};
virtual void OnFrontDisconnected(int nReason){};
virtual void OnHeartBeatWarning(int nTimeLapse){};
...
};

class MD_API_EXPORT CThostFtdcMdApi
{
public:
static CThostFtdcMdApi *CreateFtdcMdApi();
virtual void RegisterSpi(CThostFtdcMdSpi *pSpi) = 0;
...
}
```

MdSpi defines some callback function behaviors.
MdApi need to call RegisterSpi(CThostFtdcMdSpi *pSpi) to register those callback functions
This is how I want to use this in python

```
class Quote(CThostFtdcMdSpi):
def OnFrontConnected(self):
    pass

def OnFrontDisconnected(self, *args):
    pass

md = CThostFtdcMdApi_CreateFtdcMdApi()
q = Quote()
md.RegisterSpi(q)
```

Python gave this error message:

```
def RegisterSpi(self, *args): return _MdApi.CThostFtdcMdApi_RegisterSpi(self, *args)
TypeError: in method 'CThostFtdcMdApi_RegisterSpi', argument 2 of type 'CThostFtdcMdSpi *'
```

This is my MdApi.i. Both MdApi and MdSpi are defined in ThostFtdcMdApi.h

```
%module MdApi
%{
#include "ThostFtdcMdApi.h"
%}

%feature("director") CThostFtdcMdSpi;
%feature("director") CThostFtdcMdApi;

%include "ThostFtdcMdApi.h"
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without more code, but this looks like it could be something related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840706/use-method-inherited-from-abtract-c-class-in-a-python-class-swig ... If so, try defining `__init__`, and calling your super constructor.

Comment: The first part of my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040669/how-can-i-implement-a-c-class-in-python-to-be-called-by-c/9042139#9042139 should be a fully worked example of this.

Comment: Have you tried using `%feature("director")` as described in the SWIG docs and as shown in the SWIG example that come with the distro? Please show the .i file you used.

Comment: @Flexo I use % feature("director"), but error still exist.

Comment: @Schollii I uploaded my .i file as well. am I using it in a wrong fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing enabling directors at the module level. The first line of your .i file needs to be:

```
%module(directors="1") MdApi
```

From the [directors documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn33):

> The director feature is disabled by default. To use directors you must make two changes to the interface file. First, add the "directors" option to the %module directive, like this:
>
> ```
> %module(directors="1") modulename
> ```
>
> Without this option no director code will be generated. Second, you must use the `%feature("director")` directive to tell SWIG which classes and methods should get directors.

Comment: Oh, you are right. That's a stupid mistake! Thanks, it solved my problem!